# IE not opening the page

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a page you can see it here http://ksmovement.pl/cms/index.php?lang=pl

you can open this page with any browser except IE

perhaps anybody know why?

Comment: What happens with IE? What's special about the page?

Answer (score 1):

Unclosed tag in the head;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cms/templates/movement-sidebar/sh/shadowbox.css">
```

There are also errors in all.js (F12 for developer tools, reload, look at the console) probably caused by the above.